# My cakephp project not working in wampserver

Tags: cakephp

I have cakephp project running on xampp.
After a while I installed wamppserver, it shows all the link is 404 not found....

Is there anything to be changed in wampp `.htaccess` files?

Comment: “I have done a CakePHP in XAMPP”. Sounds messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't have **mod_rewrite** enabled on your localhost. Solution:

1. In the **httpd.conf** file in apache, change the line “AllowOverride
   None” to “**AllowOverride All**”.
2. Also, search for the line in the httpd.conf file with the word
   “**mod_rewrite**”, and remove the pound(#) from the start of the line.
3. After this is done, and the file is saved, **restart your
   wampserver**, and try again!

[source](http://tricksbycinger.blogspot.com/2011/05/cakephp-url-not-found-404-error-message.html)

Answer (score 1):

### Mod rewrite

Almost certainly you are missing mod rewrite. Check [the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html#apache-and-mod-rewrite-and-htaccess) for more info but in summary:

- AllowOverride needs to be "All" in the relevant section of your apache.conf file
- The .htaccess files need to be present in your CakePHP application root, app, and app/webroot folders.

If the .htaccess files are missing you can copy them from [the](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/.htaccess) [github](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/app/.htaccess) [repo](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/app/webroot/.htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your php version is 5.4?

Search for

```
'level' => E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED,
```

in app/core.php and change it to

```
'level' => E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT,
```

Comment: I would only hide `E_STRICT` messages if they would cause a problem in the CakePHP core. That might be the case, but so far I've not seen any indication for it.

Comment: Yes you're right, but there were some compatibility issues due to the inclusion of E_STRICT in E_ALL error level in PHP 5.4